# "Heap Blocks: " Number meaning on Query Plan for a bitmap heap + index scan

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

What does the number next to Heap Blocks represent in the query plan? I'm not sure if it means the # of blocks (8kb per) of data located on disk representing your data, or in some way the bitmap, which correlates more closely to idea of exact/lossy.
I initially thought it was the former, but I saw in this video (https://youtu.be/UXKYAZOWDgk?t=753) that even with 4mb of work_mem, he could still hold ~2800 heap blocks, which would amount to like 22mb, correct?

Comment: Based on some more reading I've been doing, it seems those 2800 heap blocks are not read into memory at once but get pulled into buffer( w/ back pressure based on database resources(?)). Is that true?

Comment: I am not entirety certain which part of the execution plan you are talking about. Could you post the plan for reference?

Comment: i appreciate the response but I think I got what I wanted from jjanes. But it is a line item in the bitmap heap scan, shown in the video a little further up ahead. (https://youtu.be/UXKYAZOWDgk?t=774).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4MB was enough to hold **references** to 2964 heap blocks (plus sub-references to 3531 tuples falling within those blocks).  It doesn't hold the blocks themselves.  The blocks themselves would be held in shared_buffers (Or cycled through shared_buffers if it were insufficient to hold them all), not in work_mem.